# c++ how to build a library

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using eclipse ide, Kepler service release 1 under ubuntu 12.04.
I made a library named my_lib.h. I have three functions inside that library, fun1, fun2, fun3.
Then I include this library in another .cpp file by :

```
#include <my_lib.h>
int main(){
    fun1();
    fun2();
    fun3();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I get an error for fun3, `fun3 could not be resloved`
I define fun3 inside .cpp directly and at the same time inside the .h file like this:

```
#include <my_lib.h>
void fun3(){
    //do something
}
int main(){
    fun1();
    fun2();
    fun3();
    return 0;
}
```

Then I have an eorror : `redefinition for fun3`
Finally, I delete fun3 from .h file and keep fun3 in the .cpp file to make it works. I want to put all those functions inside .h file, anyone know how to fix it?

Here is the related part from the my_lib.h file

```
#ifndef MY_LIB_H_
#define MY_LIB_H_
template <class T>
void print_matrix(const T& the_matrix){
    for(uint32 row = 0; row < the_matrix.size(); ++row){
    for(uint32 col = 0; col < the_matrix.size(); ++col){
        std::cout << the_matrix[row][col] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
}
template <class T>
void print_vector(const T& the_vector){
for(typename T::const_iterator p = the_vector.begin()
        ; p != the_vector.end(); ++p){
    std::cout << *p << "\n";
}
/*
for(uint32 i = 0; i < the_vector.size(); ++i){
    std::cout << the_vector[i] << "\n";
}
*/
}
template <class T>
double my_mean(const T& v){
    return accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) / v.size();
}
#endif /* MY_LIB_H_ */
```

function print_matrix and print_vector is fine, but the last one has the problem.

Comment: You want the function *definitions* directly inside the `.h` file? This is probably a bad design decision, but you do it with the [`inline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) keyword. Just write `inline` directly before your function, like this: `inline void fun3() { //... }`. `inline` means roughly "you will see this definition many times".

Comment: Is the `fun3()` *defined* or *declared* in `my_lib.h`?

Comment: @BoBTFish, Thank you, but it is not working. Also, may I ask what is the better design decision?

Comment: @Lmis, if I defined fun3() only in my_lib.h then I cannot resolved in .cpp, if I defined fun3() in both files, I will have an error redefinition for fun3()

Comment: @sflee Inline is for "small" functions. Instead of making a function call (which involves some overhead such as copying the arguments) the compiler will inline the function if you specify that keyword (it also does it by itself sometimes when you let it optimize). This means that it "copy-pastes" the function body right to where the call is. That ofc, requires that the *definition* of the function in question is in included in the source file to be compiled. An example would be something like `int my_formula(int x,int y) { 2*x + y}`

Comment: Having read through your question and my answer again, I see that I was off. Can you maybe show us (the relevant parts of) my_lib.h?

Comment: This is very weird to me. It seems like `#include` isn't quite doing what you'd expect (copy-past the header in). If you give the compiler the `-E` flag it will only perform the operations of the preprocessor (stuff beginning with `#`. If you remove all the other `#includes` from your header and source you might be able to see, what `#include<my_lib.h>` really does...